# How to create tool bar at the bottom when click menu button(left side button ) using android

Tags: android

I have a touch screen samsung android mobile. I need to create the toolbar when i press the menu button(left side button). My question is how to find the left side button pressed. How to code to find the mobile button pressed.

Comment: y nobody give answer for this, is it need to change question format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please research on the topic on Internet first....
There are lots of tutorials available for you.

[Create Menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

Comment: sry i have no idea how to search this menu in google. i just tried like tool bar but i vant find links for this exact